# MySQL Select statement - value name from other table

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables. One has a list of baseball players associated with numbers representing their position on the field, and the other table has a list of numbers associated with the names of the field positions.

Using a select statement, how do I select the position number from the players table, and have it show the position name (converting the position number to the name)?

I'm new to MySQL, so please keep it simple and informative. Thank you!

Comment: Use a join. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Just join the two tables on the number column.

See MYSQL JOINS HERE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Here is an example, since I don't know your actual schema.

```
SELECT pt.player_name as PLAYERNAME, fp.position_name as POSITION
FROM playersTable AS pt
INNER JOIN fieldPositions AS fp ON fp.position_number = pt.position_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
SELECT pf.position_name as position, p.position_number as playerName
FROM field_positions as pf, player as p
WHERE fp.position_number = p.position_number
```